Workflow edit button
I am using AEM 6.5.15.
After creating the workflow model, whenever i am trying to edit the workflow, the Edit button is not responding.
This issue is happening even for OOTB workflows also.
Can anyone please provide the possible cause and solution for this?

Created a workflow model , provided the title and clicked on 'Create'.
Selected the particular workflow, and clicked on Edit option
The edit button is not responding and hence not able to edit any workflow.


Any error in logs? AEM error.log or Console/network tab?

No such known issue has been reported in Adobe release notes for 6.5.15 version. But still you can try following:
Go to /system/console/configMgr/com.day.cq.wcm.core.WCMRequestFilter
Check if the WCM mode is set to "Edit"
If WCM mode is set to Edit then check the error logs.
